Can people still answer my questions if I delete my account?
I know if I delete my account, my question still remains.
Can people still answer my questions if I delete my account?

... know if I delete my account, my question still remains..., it's not always like that. See A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers

Does this answer your question? A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers

Yes they can but if they have questions about what you've asked, you won't be able to respond.
Nor will you be able to ask them anything if you don't understand the answer, and of course you won't be able to accept the answer in the case that you did understand it and found it helpful.

The profile deletion process may also automatically delete certain questions under specific circumstances. Unanswered, unscored questions tend to be good candidates for this kind of removal.
